# How do I place this TextView onto this Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity for which I obviously have a layout. The layout's background is an image and the TextView placement needs to be in a precise place. When I place the TextView in any layout, the position doesn't change with the scaling of the background image as I expect.

How do I get the TextView to scale based on the size of the screen?

The simplest solution will be accepted.

[image: bart speech bubble]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but assuming what you're going for is 'put the TextView over the speech bubble in the above image', you may have a bit of work ahead of you. You could attempt to use margins and such to give it a precise placement over the speech image, but this will be quite tricky and will probably never work exactly like you want. Your simplest option would be to do the following

1. Use Photoshop, Paint, or just about any editing program to cut out Bart and the speech bubble and save them as seperate images.
2. Use a RelativeLayout with the background color set to black `android:background="@android:color/black"`.
3. Place an ImageView using the graphic of Bart, and set the following properties on it: `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, and `android:id="@id/img_bart".
4. Place a TextView, set the background to use the speech bubble image (`android:background="@drawable/img_speech"` or whatever you called the speech bubble image), set it to appear to the right of Bart `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_bart"`, and either snap it to the top (`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` - this may cause issues on tall screens though), or snap to the bottom offset by an appropriate amount through `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"`, modifying the 150 to get it to appear at the right height relative to Bart.

I know it's a fair bit of work, unfortunately Android layouts often are, especially in cases where you want to get different elements to stick together in appropriate ways, like speech bubbles.

Another thing you could look at is AbsoluteLayout, which allows you to place child elements in *exact* locations - however this is strongly discouraged as it won't scale well to different screen sizes, and the AbsoluteLayout class itself is deprecated and has been for a very long time.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that there is no "simple" answer to this question so I have chosen to accept this answer based on the criteria presented in the question and the breadth of your answer. I have concluded that, in order to get what I want, I would have to create my own layout class and arrange top,left,bottom,right based on a sane scheme (percentage of distance from the edge of each side of the Activity).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would to be to, if they are not already, create 2 images out of this. One being Bart, and the other being a speech bubble.
Create the ImageViews for each image, set Bart to the bottom left, and the speech bubble to the top right.
You can then create your TextView as being size:wrap_content, and stretch it to the size of the bubble. Then setting the gravity of the TextView to center, you will be able to have all of your text centered inside of the speech bubble.